# Code for internal function Which returns arguments when used

Tags: r

I am  using **mirt** pcakge. While using `itemfit` function in it, to know what is going in that function I debugged it and came across an internal function which called ProabTrace. I am not able to see the code of this function. I tried following things:

```
mirt:::ProbTrace
standardGeneric for "ProbTrace" defined from package "mirt"

function (x, Theta, ...) 
standardGeneric("ProbTrace")
<bytecode: 0x00000000086fe398>
<environment: 0x00000000086c1bf8>
Methods may be defined for arguments: x, Theta
Use  showMethods("ProbTrace")  for currently available ones.


showMethods("ProbTrace")
Function: ProbTrace (package mirt)
x="custom", Theta="matrix"
x="dich", Theta="matrix"
x="gpcm", Theta="matrix"
x="graded", Theta="matrix"
x="ideal", Theta="matrix"
x="nestlogit", Theta="matrix"
x="nominal", Theta="matrix"
x="partcomp", Theta="matrix"
x="rating", Theta="matrix"
x="rsm", Theta="matrix"
```

I don't know how to proceed from here. I thought it would return some object so that I can use the `getMethod` function to get the code. But that is not happening.

Any help please.

Best,
Irshad

Comment: Try [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function)

Comment: Thank you, @DavidArenburg! 
That link helped! :)